# Does Hyperledger Fabric store failed transactions?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Does Hyperledger Fabric store failed transactions? Is it stored in the ledger or somewhere else?

Answer (score 4):

There can be multiple points where a transaction can "fail" along a [transaction flow](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/txflow.html) route. If the transaction "fails" before it is successfully submitted to the ordering service, it does *not* end up in the ledger.

After the Tx is ordered, the peer will put the Tx in its ledger and then run its own validity check. If the Tx fails validity, it will still be in ledger but with an "invalid" tag in the peer.